# SQL query to pull unique (non-duplicate) values prioritized and ordered by dates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

There is a table with monthly reports that include inventory data for each month of the year. I want to be able to pull every item that was reported for the year and the data associated. I want to be able to remove duplicates prioritizing the most recent report. So all `item ids` on the December report, then all `item ids` on the November report that are not on the December report, then all `item ids` on the October report that are not on the December & November report, etc.

Here is what I have so far. (I am insanely new to this).

```
SELECT * Table Name
WHERE Cast(REPORTDATE AS DATE)
BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
AND Store Code = 'Store 1'
Order BY ReportDate DESC
```

This is an example of what I get:

| ReportDate | Item ID | Store Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 15 | Item A | Store 1 |
| Dec 15 | Item B | Store 1 |
| Dec 15 | Item C | Store 1 |
| Nov 15 | Item A | Store 1 |
| Nov 15 | Item B | Store 1 |
| Nov 15 | Item C | Store 1 |
| Nov 15 | Item E | Store 1 |

This is what I want:

| ReportDate | Item ID | Store Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 15 | Item A | Store 1 |
| Dec 15 | Item B | Store 1 |
| Dec 15 | Item C | Store 1 |
| Nov 15 | Item E | Store 1 |

Comment: When asking SQL questions, please always show both sample input and expected result

Answer (score 0):

This should work based on your input and desired output.  You can see it in action over at [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eksVQv4Ji8vzsjcSL7qAKq/0) if you want to explore it a little more.

```sql
SELECT MAX(reportdate) as ReportDate,
       ItemID,
       StoreCode
  FROM t
 WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
   AND StoreCode = 'Store 1'
 group by ItemID, StoreCode
 order by ReportDate DESC, ItemID
```